# X and Y axis doesn' t work on Bada 2.0

Tags: axis, bada, construct

I' ve downloaded an example app from Bada documentation, DigitalLocker, and I' ve done and I' m doing some test, I had some problems, but with some help I solved, now I have another problem with X and Y axis in Item forms (personalIdItem, webacco, ecc..). I can modify correctly width and height of editfield, editarea and checkbutton, but also if I put X and Y axis they still remain on the left, and don' t know why.

```
EditField* pFName;
    pFName = new EditField();
    pFName->Construct(Rectangle(80, 80, 220, 110), EDIT_FIELD_STYLE_NORMAL, 
                            INPUT_STYLE_FULLSCREEN, true, 30, GROUP_STYLE_SINGLE);
    pFName->SetTitleText(getMed);
    pFName->SetTextSize(35);
```

`Rectangle(X,Y,width,height)` the first 2 doesn' t work the other 2 width and height yes.

If you want try you can download this app from Bada Documentation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ReDraw()` once and `Refresh()`